# How to echo specific elements from a database

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo certain elements from my news table throughout an article. This involves fields such as the author, headline, content and date. At the moment I can only echo the row and any attempt to echo elements in the page itself is either met with small errors or it outputs nothing. I've had a look around and only found people having problems with simply printing out the row database which I can already do.

Basically when I have Author in my article I want to echo author from my database and it will show next to Author. I'm not sure how possible it is as I am yet to find anything on this or I'm overlooking it.

Here is my current PHP file and I've left in the initial part with the article author, date and headline.

```
<?php

/* Database connection settings */
$host = 'xxxxx';
$user = 'xxxxx';
$pass = 'xxxxx';
$db = 'xxxxx';

$dbconnect=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

if ($dbconnect->connect_error) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . $dbconnect->connect_error);
}


 $query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "SELECT * FROM news WHERE news_Id = 1")
   or die (mysqli_errr($dbconnect));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo
   "<tr>
    <td>{$row['headline']}</td>
    <td>{$row['content']}</td>
    <td>{$row['author']}</td>
    <td>{$row['date']}</td>   
   </tr>\n";

}

?>
<div class="container-fluid bg">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="container">         
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="news-title">
                                    <h2><?php echo $row['headline']; ?></h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="news-cats">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline mb-1">
                                         <li class="list-inline-item">
                                                <i class="fa fa-folder-o text-danger"></i>
                                                <a href="#"><small>Author:</small> </a>
                                        </li>
                                         <li class="list-inline-item">
                                                <i class="fa fa-folder-o text-danger"></i>
                                                <a href="#"><small>Posted:</small></a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
```

Comment: This seems pretty basic, what have you tried? How about [`if`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)?

Comment: Does your query only return one row?

Comment: Yes @Nick it only returns one row which is what I want but I want to actually echo the data such as headline, author etc throughout my html. Like so <h2><?php echo $row['headline']; ?></h2>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your query only returns one row, a `while` loop is inappropriate for fetching the data, as at the end of the loop, `$row` will be left as a `false` value, thus making any attempt to access e.g. `$row['headline']` fail. Change your `while` loop

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
```

to a simple assignment:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) or die(mysqli_error($dbconnect));
```

Note you have a typo earlier in your code,

```
or die (mysqli_errr($dbconnect));
```

should be

```
or die (mysqli_error($dbconnect));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just printing out the result, but don't have a label. You can add one like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo
   "<tr>
    <td>Headline: {$row['headline']}</td>
    <td>Content: {$row['content']}</td>
    <td>Author: {$row['author']}</td>
    <td>Date: {$row['date']}</td>   
   </tr>\n";

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I'm trying to echo that data in the html. That was just an example of what I've done so far. For example, if you scroll down to the <div class="news-title"> and look at the <h2> tags I would like to echo headline in there.